# RangeBar with drag and click operations and should allow gap between thumbs in Android

Tags: android

is their any library which performs click operation on RangeBar and should also maintain fixed gap between left thumb and right thumb.

[image: Image of libary which am using]

[library Source](https://github.com/oli107/material-range-bar)

this libary not allowing to maintain fixed gap between left and right thumbs.